# Drupal Translation Doesn't work

Tags: theming, 8, i18n-l10n, transliteration

I am trying to translate articles/nodes on my site. I installed all required modules.
[image]

I have a custom node type.

[image]

This custom node type has some fields that are translatable and not translatable.

[image]

I checked this checkbox 
[image]

I created custom view for the front page that contains nodes of custom type.
But when I switch the language translation doesn't work.

Menu translation works. But the view nodes are not translated.

The interesting thing that if I visit my node by a full url path like this

`http://test.net/node/1`

Translation works fine.

I am outputting node properties in my template in the following way

```
          {{ node.title.value }}
   {{ node.field_description.value|raw }}
    {{ node.field_custom_body.value|raw }}
```

What can be wrong ?

**EDIT**

I have no option `Content language selected for page`

[image]

My view looks like this now

P.S I am using language switcher block to change language and it sets the session variable

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure a filter for the language in the the view:

FILTER CRITERIA

"Content: Translation language (= Content language selected for page)"

---

Btw. you have a big security problem in the node template, it is not allowed to apply the raw filter on a field that contains user input. You should use

```
{{ content.field_custom_body }}
```

instead to print the field.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !! Appreciate it, but I have a problem I have not `Content language selected for page`, please see my edit

Comment: You can use the interface language if you not have configured a content language. You can configure both separately, but you don't need to.

Comment: thanks, I've just set this option but when I change language I get an empty page ( (I've added configuration screen in my question)

Comment: If you are sure that you have translated content which should pass all filters, then you have a problem with the language detection. I would start with only "URL" detection method enabled.

Comment: it works well, menu is translated, and single node url works well

Comment: a view should work as well, switch all filters off except for the content language and see if one of them blocks the nodes, perhaps you have not published the translations or something else, can't debug this from here

Comment: thanks for answer, but I still have this problem, if you have the Drupal forum  account, I would be grateful if you could help me in this forum thread https://www.drupal.org/node/2859591